# Резиновое видео

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Есть такая структура страницы: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно адаптировать под 3 разрешения экрана: 1920x1080 and 2160x1440 and 2736x1574
Проблема в том, что видео нужно растянуть на максимальную ширину и высоту, но оставить место под меню, а значит -250px. 
Также видео может быть рандомных разрешений, поэтому если растягивать и получится "не красиво" - не имеет значения. Лишь бы растянулось :)

Вот [ссылка](http://atomr-web.github.io/isuzu/).
Спасибо.

Comment: `height:calc(100% - 250px);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: @Igor вообщем, вот ссылка http://atomr-web.github.io/isuzu/. Применил предложенное правило для css - не совсем то, что нужно. Нужно что бы видео полностью по ширине растянулось и встало под "HOME". Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @atomrr где должно остаться место под меню? Убрав height:calc(100% - 250px); у Вас оно растягивается по ширине и высоте.

Comment: @Anthony_L посмотрите, пожалуйста, вот ссылка http://atomr-web.github.io/isuzu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
video {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#myVideo {
    width: 2000px;
    min-width: 720px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 350px;
/*     background: url(../images/video-bg.png) center no-repeat; */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 3;
}

#section0 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 770px) {
  #section0 {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 350px !important;
      min-height: 350px;
      height: 100% !important;
      display: block;
  }
}

#section0 .layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.34);
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap_video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.site__title {
    display: block;
    line-height: .8;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- Background video section : Start -->
<div class="custom-video section" data-section="about">
  <div class="video_section" id="section0">
    <video autoplay loop muted id="myVideo">
      <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/distill-videos/videos/processed/9/MVI_0358.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/distill-videos/videos/processed/9/MVI_0358.mp4.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div class="layer">
      <div class="wrap wrap_video">
        
        <h1 class="site__title">Section Title </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>                    
</div><!-- Background video section : End -->
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.menu{
  background-color: gray;
  height: 250px;
}

.video{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 250px);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 250px
</div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w6DW4i-mfbA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe>
```

Если вам нужна реализация конкретно под ваш случай, то используйте

.video-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

Comment: видео будет использоваться локально и при помощи calc я пробовал. Не получилось, к сожалению. Залил на гп, взгляните, пожалуйста. http://atomr-web.github.io/isuzu/

Comment: @Atomrr, обратите внимание: #video { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```